# Printing Java Binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

How to print out a binary search tree in java? I have written the code to insert to the tree but without being able to print the tree i am insure if the elements are adding. I will post my code below.

```
public class TreeNode {

    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode root;

    int data;

    public TreeNode(int d) {

        data = d;
        left = right = null;
        root = null;

    }

    public synchronized void insert(int d) {
        if (root == null){
            root = new TreeNode( d );
        }
        if (d < data) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new TreeNode(d);
            } else {
                left.insert(d);
            }
        } else if (d > data) {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new TreeNode(d);
            } else {
                right.insert(d);
            }
        }
    }

    public TreeNode treeSearch(TreeNode root, int target) {
        if (root != null) {
            if (target < root.data) {
                root = treeSearch(root.left, target);
            } else if (target > root.data) {
                root = treeSearch(root.right, target);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: there are at least too many ways of printing it. Can you provide a simple input and desired output? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Its hard to explain the way i would like it but i will try. The output should output the root first then the lower level with the outputs branching off the root and then a lower level branching off this etc depending on the values inserted.

Comment: I think you missed the "**Can you provide a simple input and desired output?**" part while reading my comment. This meant editing the question, so everybody can easily see that, without looking at the comments

Comment: @Bryan I think you mean the Preorder traversal. For more info : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Comment: Thank you will check it out now!

Answer (score 4):

You may use following method:

```
 void printTree(TreeNode node, String prefix)
 {
    if(node == null) return;

    System.out.println(prefix + " + " + node.data);
    printTree(node.left , prefix + " ");
    printTree(node.right , prefix + " ");
 }
```

Initial call should be `printTree( root,"");` from where you want to print the tree. Here `root` is reference of root node.

**UPDATED:**
You can see this code working [here](https://ideone.com/VqPSA7)

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you please explain this method in more detail.

Comment: @Bryan This method use `recursion-method` to print the tree. First parameter is the node which is going to be printed and second argument is a `String` having spaces for better visibility of tree. This method returns if `node` is `null`. if it is not null then it prints `data` part and call itself for `left` and `right` child.

Comment: Thank you for further explanation!

Comment: your method has not solved it exactly but it has given me a basis to try modify and tweak it to what i want exactly!

Comment: @Bryan What is not covered in this answer?

Comment: When i use this method for some reason my program crashes when i try to delete an element but when this method is commented out when i try delete although i cannot see if it deletes or not the program runs without crashing

Comment: @Bryan Can you update the code in question? Or provide the link on of your code like on __[ideone](https://ideone.com/)__ So that I can reproduce the error?

Comment: Please view https://ideone.com/Mw4iX6 to view my code. Please note in the method to print it is modified slightly but even when its the same as you wrote the error still occurs when trying to delete.

Comment: sorry forgot to tag you @cse

Comment: @Bryan It dose'n contains the code for `main` and adding the nodes. Please provide the same.

Comment: @Bryan Provided code is working fine. You can see it working [here](https://ideone.com/VqPSA7)

Comment: One minor suggestion, you could put the print statement in the middle, it will print the tree similar to inorder traversal output, it makes it look more like a BST

Answer (score 0):

you can print the tree data like this.

```
public void printTree(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) return;
        System.out.println(root.data);
        printTree(root.left);
        printTree(root.right);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void print(PrintWriter out) {
    print(root, out, "");
}

private void print(TreeNode subtree, PrintWriter out, String indent) {
    if (subtree != null) {
        print(subtree.left, out, indent + "--");
        out.printf("%s %s%n", indent, subtree.data);
        print(subtree.right, out, indent + "--");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Infix order: Left - root - right

```
public String printInfix(TreeNode root) {//prints all the words in the tree in infix order
    if(root==null) {
        return "";
    }

     return printAll(root.left+" "+root.data+" "+printAll(root.right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printTree(TreeNode node, String prefix)
    {
        if(node == null) return;

        printTree(node.right , prefix + "   ");
        System.out.println(prefix + node.data);
        printTree(node.left , prefix + "   ");
       
    }
```

Prints the tree in BST structure flatly